# How to mutate() a list of columns using map2() in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I recently had to compile a data frame of student scores (one row per student, id column and several integer-valued columns, one per score component). I had to combine a "master" data frame and several "correction" data frames (containing mostly `NA` and some updates to the master), so that the result contains the maximum values from the master, and all corrections.

I succeeded by copy-pasting a sequence of `mutate()` calls, which works (see example below), but is not elegant in my opinion. What I would have wanted to do, was instead of copying and pasting, to use something along the lines of `map2` and two lists of columns to compare the columns pair-wise. Something like (which obviously does not work as such):

```
list_of_cols1 <- list(col1.x, col2.x, col3.x)
list_of_cols2 <- list(col1.y, col2.y, col3.y
map2(list_of_cols1, list_of_cols2, ~ column = pmax(.x, .y, na.rm=T))
```

I can't seem to be able to figure out to do it. My question is: how to specify such lists of columns and mutate them in one `map2()` call in `dplyr` pipe, or is it even possible – have I gotten it all wrong?

Minimum working example

```
library(tidyverse)

master <- tibble(
  id=c(1,2,3), 
  col1=c(1,1,1),
  col2=c(2,2,2),
  col3=c(3,3,3)
)
correction1 <- tibble(
  id=seq(1,3),
  col1=c(NA, NA, 2 ),
  col2=c( 1, NA, 3 ),
  col3=c(NA, NA, NA)
)

result <- reduce(
  # Ultimately there would several correction data frames
  list(master, correction1), 
  function(x,y) {
    x <- x %>% 
      left_join(
        y,
        by = c("id")
      ) %>%
      # Wish I knew how to do this mutate call with map2 
      mutate(
        col1 = pmax(col1.x, col1.y, na.rm=T), 
        col2 = pmax(col2.x, col2.y, na.rm=T), 
        col3 = pmax(col3.x, col3.y, na.rm=T)
      ) %>%
      select(id, col1:col3)
  }
)
```

The result is

```
> result
# A tibble: 3 x 4
     id  col1  col2  col3
  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1     2     3
2     2     1     2     3
3     3     2     3     3
```

Comment: To clarify, a correction should only be made if the value is greater than what's in the `master`?

Comment: Good question, but no, the goal is to find the greatest value in the `master` and `correction1` (and `correction2`, `correction3`, etc.) tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than do a `left_join`, just bind the rows then summarize. For example

```
result <- reduce(
  list(master, master), 
  function(x,y) {
    bind_rows(x, y) %>%
      group_by(id) %>%
      summarize_all(max, na.rm=T)
  }
)
result
#     id  col1  col2  col3
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     1     2     3
# 2     2     1     2     3
# 3     3     2     3     3
```

Actually, you don't even need reduce as `bind_rows` can take a list

Adding another table

```
correction2 <- tibble(id=2,col1=NA,col2=8,col3=NA)
bind_rows(master, correction1, correction2) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarize_all(max, na.rm=T)
```

Comment: Ah the simplicity! I didn't even think that I could just go row-wise, instead of comparing columns. This was the first answer and beautifully simple.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry this doesn't answer your question about `map2`, I find it's easier to aggregate over rows than it is over columns in `tidy` R:

```r
library(dplyr)

master <- tibble(
  id=c(1,2,3), 
  col1=c(1,1,1),
  col2=c(2,2,2),
  col3=c(3,3,3)
)
correction1 <- tibble(
  id=seq(1,3),
  col1=c(NA, NA, 2 ),
  col2=c( 1, NA, 3 ),
  col3=c(NA, NA, NA)
)

result <- list(master, correction1) %>% 
  bind_rows() %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise_all(max, na.rm = TRUE)

result
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>      id  col1  col2  col3
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     1     2     3
#> 2     2     1     2     3
#> 3     3     2     3     3
```

Answer (score 1):

If `correction` tables will always have the same structure as `master`, you can do something like the following:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

update_master = function(...){
  map(list(...), as.matrix) %>%
    reduce(pmax, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
    data.frame()
}

update_master(master, correction1)
```

To allow `id` to take character values, make the following modification:

```
update_master = function(x, ...){
  map(list(x, ...), function(x) as.matrix(x[-1])) %>%
    reduce(pmax, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
    data.frame(id = x[[1]], .)
}

update_master(master, correction1)
```

**Result:**

```
  id col1 col2 col3
1  1    1    2    3
2  2    1    2    3
3  3    2    3    3
```